# c# windows service config file

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a C# .net Windows Service that has a config file.

I am reading the settings of the config file from my code using

```
string setting1 = Properties.Settings.Default.setting1;
```

If I change the value of setting1 directly in the .config file of the Windows Service for some reason it maintains the value that I had set for it at design time, in the Settings Dialog of the Project.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong ..

Thanks

Comment: can you post how you are starting the service and which files you are modifying and in which directories?

Answer (score 1):

You have the settings as User scope in place of Application scope.

The user scope settings are in user AppData folder. You can delete it in the AppData folder of the user under whose credentials the windows service runs.

Comment: no the Scope in the Settings Dialog is set to Application for all settings

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the service?  I don't think they support dynamic reloading by default.

[this question might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884260/how-can-i-watch-the-user-config-file-and-reload-the-settings-when-it-changes)  [or maybe this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502411/change-connection-string-reload-app-config-at-run-time)

but the gist seems to be to reload the settings using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Seeing as its a service you might want to add a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch the file and call reload when it is changed.

Comment: well, I do set all of the settings in teh config file before starting the service - but it seems to ignore whatever I put in ..