# What isn't my c# application setting showing up in the user.config file?

Tags: c#

I have just added a setting into my application settings for my C# app. I can access the setting just fine in my code using Settings.Default.MySetting, and it's in the app.config file in my project. But no matter what I do, it never shows up in the user.config file for my application. What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: User-scoped config file is stored in User folder, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884260/how-can-i-watch-the-user-config-file-and-reload-the-settings-when-it-changes

Comment: Right, and I can delete it, run my app and the file will show up again, but the setting I've just added isn't in there. Why?

Comment: What's reload? Not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

In the settings designer you of course need to set the scope to `User`.

The `<userSettings>` section in app.config is the place where defaults are stored.

Assuming your application provides a way for the user to change their settings, the settings system will write the overridden values to the *user*.config the first time you call the `configuration.Save()` method.

also note that "user" in user.config is replaced by the user name of the identity under which the configuration was saved.

Comment: So the only way I can get it to work is to write a value to my config value, then call Settings.Default.Save(). Then the entry shows up in the user.config. Something is wrong, why to I have to make fake changes to config settings before they show up in user.config? Or maybe my problem is more fundamental, and I shouldn't be using user.config like an application config file?

Comment: I recommend you make a *real* change to the setting and save it.  Until then, the default value will suffice.  If you can't come up with a scenario for a real change then it probably shouldn't be a setting.

Comment: @JonathanBeerhalter Why do you need something other than the default value unless it has changged?